# Get body of request within Axios error object

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

It is fairly well documented that on error, the Axios Error object will contain the response and request.

On a failed POST, I want to access the request body for logging purposes, but I do not know how

```
try {
  await axios.post('http://example.com', { test: data }, { 'content-type': 'application/json' })
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.response.data)
  console.log(error.request.data)      // Undefined, should be '{ test: data }'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The body is in the Axios config property

```
try {
  await axios.post('http://example.com', { test: data }, { 'content-type': 'application/json' })
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.response.data)
  console.log(error.config.data)
}
```